# Is it possible to do region folding on the Powershell ISE output pane?

Tags: powershell, formatting, powershell-ise

It would be really convenient if one could collapse an error on the output pane or just collapse the output of a command in the output pane. I searched for extensions and checked extensions like 'ISESteroids'. But couldn't find this functionality with any of the extensions.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. It looks like you can request this at the [feedback site](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell), though.

Comment: The editor in ISE is based on components from Visual Studio. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee197665.aspx) is a somewhat random page from VS studio documentation on extensions that kind of points in the right direction. You may have to use private members to access the functionality related to outlining. (I was able to change the ISE tab size by using private members.)

Comment: @user2460798 I wish there was an extension I could install. I just know powershell. I am an admin and not very familiar with VB or C#.

Comment: I wish there was too

Comment: "The editor in ISE is based on components from Visual Studio" - The OP is asking about the output pane (the console in ISE 3 and newer), not the editor.

Comment: A Powershell MVP said that it isn't possible to achieve this in ISE's output pane or in the normal Powershell console and that it wouldn't help to post it as a feature-suggestion. But this could be done in Visual studio. I'll check and confirm.